# How to connect HC-05 to an arduino Galileo?

Tags: uart, arduino-galileo

I connected a logic analyzer on digital pins 0 and 1 (Rx and Tx). Using `Serial.` functions on Galileo and the integrated terminal on Arduino IDE, I noticed this UART port was not used when chars were received and transmitted, what is sustained by the blocks diagram of Galileo [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileoLogicSchematics.jpg).

So, if UART1 is used on PC communications, I would like to use UART0 to other things, like a bluetooth adapter. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://alextgalileo.altervista.org/blog/galileo-uart-and-arduino-serial-objects-mapping/) might answer your questions about the Serial mapping on Galileo. Seems like you should use Serial1 for UART0 and Serial2 for UART1.

Cheers!